# How to pass attribute ID to ngCLass condition

Tags: angular

In this code :

```
  <div id="navi-div"> 
  <div class="navi-button" id="dashboard" (click)="goTo($event)"  [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': selectedEvent === id}">Dashboard Final </div>
  <div class="navi-button" id="dashboardtemp" (click)="goTo($event)" [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': selectedEvent === id}"> Dashboard Temp </div>
  </div>
```

I cannot correctly pass  id value to  [ngClass] condition.  In ngClass $event is not recognised. So, how  can I do that ?

My onCLick function:

```
  private goTo(event): void {
    let path: string = event.target.attributes.id.value; 
    this.selectedEvent = event.target.attributes.id;
    this.router.navigate([path], { queryParams: {  }});  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `#elementid` that's how an element is referenced in angular2...

```
<div id="navi-div"> 
  <div class="navi-button" id="dashboard" #dashboard (click)="goTo($event)"  [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': selectedEvent === dashboard}">Dashboard Final </div>
  <div class="navi-button" id="dashboardtemp" #dashboardtemp (click)="goTo($event)" [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': selectedEvent === dashboardtemp}"> Dashboard Temp </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would like just eviter  to passed once again  "url"   there is no other possibility ?

Comment: and how to access it from my function ?

Comment: to access it from your function you can pass it as an argument .... goTo(dashboard) as its explained here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars  hope it helps

Comment: Ah ok.. so  as second  attribute.. ok :D

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values can be accessed directly from within the tamplate.

```
<div class="navi-button" id="dashboard" #dashboard (click)="goTo($event)"  [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': dashboard.id === 'selected-dashboard'}">Dashboard Final </div>
```

or

```
<div class="navi-button" id="dashboard" #dashboard (click)="goTo($event)"  [ngClass]="{'navi-button-selected': dashboard.attributes['id'].value === 'selected-dashboard'}">Dashboard Final </div>
```